# No module name 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, module

The requirements for the code to run is

- [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)
- [TensorFlow 1.n](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)
- [SciPy & NumPy](http://scipy.org/install.html)

I have python 2.7.8 by checking python --version. Installing them on python website also lead to a message saying there is no software to install so I assumed that I already have python 2.7x

For tensorflow I have install it using pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

and for Scipy and numpy i did brew install numpy scipy ipython jupyter

I have a python env setup call mypython.

Using pip list I have the following modules install as shown in the image.

But still VScode prompt an error and say that No module named 'tensorflow'when i run the code file.

How do I solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqTcu.png)

Comment: You are using python2, and installing python3 libraries, which of course will not work. Stop using python2 and migrate to python3, as python2 is end of life and no longer supported.

Comment: But in the READ Me file. The creator mentioned to use python 2.7.

Comment: That was not a recent recommendation, probably the code is very old too.

Comment: Yep, the project was done around 5 years ago. Here's their github link. https://github.com/ShafeenTejani/fast-style-transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install **Python** extension instead of MagicPython;
2. You're using `mypython` in integrated Terminal but in left bottom corner, you select the global one,which is python3.10.1 as interpreter. Open Command Palette and choose **Python: Select Interpreter**, select `mypython` then reload window,the error should go away

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be using the wrong pip. Could you run following in your terminal, with your venv activated.

```
$ pip --version
$ pip3 --version
```

Try installing with pip instead of pip3

Comment: same problem with pip3